# memory leak issue in rails and phusion passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-leaks, passenger

The rails site was running so slow that I had to reboot the os, but after only 1 hour after rebooting ubuntu, the system was incredible slow again, so I checked the passenger memory statistics:

```
------ Passenger processes ------
PID    VMSize     Private   Name
---------------------------------
1076   215.8 MB   0.3 MB    PassengerWatchdog
1085   2022.3 MB  4.4 MB    PassengerHelperAgent
1089   109.4 MB   6.4 MB    Passenger spawn server
1093   159.2 MB   0.8 MB    PassengerLoggingAgent
1883   398.1 MB   110.1 MB  Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
1906   1174.6 MB  885.9 MB  Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
3648   370.1 MB   131.9 MB  Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
14830  370.6 MB   83.0 MB   Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
15124  401.2 MB   113.9 MB  Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
15239  413.5 MB   127.7 MB  Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
15277  400.5 MB   113.6 MB  Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
15285  357.1 MB   70.1 MB   Rack: /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/current
### Processes: 12
### Total private dirty RSS: 1648.10 MB
```

It boggles my mind how that one rack process is using 885.9 MB of private dirty RSS memory after one hour of rebooting the OS when usage was down to 100 mb total. Now one hour later it's at 1648.10 mb. The site is so slow the page won't even load.

I assume it's a memory leak so I added this line of code throughout the application:

```
puts "Object count: #{ObjectSpace.count_objects}"
```

But I do not know how to interpret the data it gives me:

```
Object count: {:TOTAL=>2379635, :FREE=>318247, :T_OBJECT=>35074, :T_CLASS=>6707, :T_MODULE=>1760, :T_FLOAT=>174, :T_STRING=>1777046, :T_REGEXP=>2821, :T_ARRAY=>75160, :T_HASH=>64227, :T_STRUCT=>774, :T_BIGNUM=>7, :T_FILE=>7, :T_DATA=>55075, :T_MATCH=>10, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_RATIONAL=>63, :T_NODE=>37652, :T_ICLASS=>4830}
```

Note I only running that ObjectSpace.count_objects on my local machine since my ubuntu server is so slow it cannot even load the page.

Here's some other OS statistics:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo                                                        
MemTotal:        6113156 kB
MemFree:         3027204 kB
Buffers:          103540 kB
Cached:           261544 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2641168 kB
Inactive:         248316 kB
Active(anon):    2524652 kB
Inactive(anon):      328 kB
Active(file):     116516 kB
Inactive(file):   247988 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       6287356 kB
SwapFree:        6287356 kB
Dirty:                36 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2524444 kB
Mapped:            30108 kB
Shmem:               568 kB
Slab:              77268 kB
SReclaimable:      48528 kB
SUnreclaim:        28740 kB
KernelStack:        4648 kB
PageTables:        43044 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9343932 kB
Committed_AS:    5179468 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      293056 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359442172 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       46848 kB
DirectMap2M:     5195776 kB

df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/roadrunner-root 134821120 22277596 105695012  18% /
udev                          3047064        4   3047060   1% /dev
tmpfs                         1222632      252   1222380   1% /run
none                             5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                          3056576       88   3056488   1% /run/shm
none                           102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                      233191    29079    191671  14% /boot
```

On a side note, if I run "kill -9 1906" to kill that one rack process consuming so much memory, would that help?

Comment: I also noticed this craziness when running the top command: 1906 guarddog 20 0 1174m 940m 4180 R 99.9 15.8 365:40.91 ruby. 99 percent cpu usage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, hot fix the immediate production problem, implement a watchdog - http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2012/08/simple-rubyrails-passenger-memory-consumption-limit-monitoring/ and then hunt for the leak, or bloat (https://blog.engineyard.com/2009/thats-not-a-memory-leak-its-bloat)
2. That process you showed *looks* like a regular worker, try killing the offending process under controlled conditions, see what happens, probably nothing bad.
3. See if you can correlate this happening with a certain (often long running) controller action, or apache restarts/reloads (have this problem on regular basis, 1 in 20 processes goes bonkers after restart).
4. Extend rails logs so they contain PIDs (https://gist.github.com/krutten/1091611 for example) and make a simple script that dumps memory use into a file every minute or so (make sure you don't fill your disk) - this will enable you to know exactly when a process started bloating and then trace in the logs what it was doing before/as this happened

Comment: Thanks for response, when you say "try killing the offending process under controlled conditions", do you mean something like  "kill -9 1906"?

Comment: Np :) Yes, but try a normal kill first (just kill 1906), see if it decides to go away peacefully (in this case its probably just application bloat). If that fails try kill -9, and monitor the app while doing so - if there's any trouble after that just restart the apache server and take a look if any of the old processes are still lingering

Comment: I was looking at the one article you linked to which referenced this: "We often recommend people try Rack::Bug, MemoryLogic or Oink". Are any of these 3 suitable for a rails 3 application?

Comment: Afaik, they're all suitable, but their use cases differ, some of them warn about performance impacts when using their tracing etc so if you want to use them it's probably best to go through the docs and see which one(s) fit your case best